# R - Cloropleth: Of the data points that fall within a polygon, what percentage have a specific column value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, choropleth, r-sf

An extension of this thread: [Create choropleth map from coordinate points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45891034/3817004). (I didn't want to combine the two threads for the sake of being relevant to as many people as possible.)

I have a data frame consisting of many observations, each with geocoordinates (latitude-longitude) and a boolean (yes-no) value. I would like to generate a choropleth map of the world where each region/polygon is shaded by the percentage of points within it where the associated boolean value is equal to true.

Here is a minimally reproducible example, which right now only shades according to the number of points in a polygon. The "like" column of data is my boolean.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(sf)

data <- data.frame(class = c("Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private"),
                   lat = c(33.663944, 41.117936, 28.049601, 39.994684, 36.786042, 12.797659, 52.923318, 33.385555, 9.295242, 32.678207, 41.833585, -28.762956, 39.284713, 36.060964, 36.052239, 36.841764, 33.714237, 33.552863, 32.678207, -38.132401),
                   lon = c(-83.98686, -77.60468, -81.97271, -82.98577, -119.78246, 121.82814, -1.16057, -86.76009, 123.27758,   -83.17387, -87.73201, 32.05737, -76.62048, -115.13517, -79.39961, -76.35592, -85.85172, -112.12468, -83.17387, 144.36946))

# Convert to simple feature object
point_sf <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Get world map data
worldmap <- maps::map("world", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

# Convert world to sp class
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(worldmap$names, ":"), "[", 1L)
world_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(worldmap, IDs = IDs, 
                                proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Convert world_sp to simple feature object
world_sf <- st_as_sf(world_sp)

# Add country ID
world_sf <- world_sf %>%
  mutate(region = map_chr(1:length(world_sp@polygons), function(i){
    world_sp@polygons[[i]]@ID
  }))

# Use st_within
result <- st_within(point_sf, world_sf, sparse = FALSE)

# Calculate the total count of each polygon
# Store the result as a new column "Count" in world_sf
world_sf <- world_sf %>%
  mutate(Count = apply(result, 2, sum))

# Convert world_sf to a data frame world_df 
world_df <- world_sf
st_geometry(world_df) <- NULL

# Get world data frame
world_data <- map_data("world")

# Merge world_data and world_df
world_data2 <- world_data %>%
  left_join(world_df, by = c("region"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = world_data2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Count)) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
```

Special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/7669809/ycw for the help thus far.

Comment: Thank you for pointing those out, I corrected the example. The "although coordinates are longitude/latitude, it is assumed that they are planar" warning is isn't meaningful and can be looked past.

Answer (score 2):

We can first count how many points in a polygon, filter the datasets for records labeled as `Private` in the `class` column, and then count how many points in the polygon again. We can later calculate the percentage by using `Private` count number dividing by all count number and multipling by 100%.

One nice feature about the `sf` object is it is also a data frame. So operations to manage a data frame, such as `filter` from the `dplyr` package, also work for the `sf` object. So we can use command like `point_private_sf <- point_sf %>% filter(class %in% "Private")` to filter the points easily.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(sf)

### Data Preparation

data <- data.frame(class = c("Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private", "Not Private", "Private", "Private", "Not Private"),
                   lat = c(33.663944, 41.117936, 28.049601, 39.994684, 36.786042, 12.797659, 52.923318, 33.385555, 9.295242, 32.678207, 41.833585, -28.762956, 39.284713, 36.060964, 36.052239, 36.841764, 33.714237, 33.552863, 32.678207, -38.132401),
                   lon = c(-83.98686, -77.60468, -81.97271, -82.98577, -119.78246, 121.82814, -1.16057, -86.76009, 123.27758,   -83.17387, -87.73201, 32.05737, -76.62048, -115.13517, -79.39961, -76.35592, -85.85172, -112.12468, -83.17387, 144.36946))

# Convert to simple feature object
point_sf <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Get world map data
worldmap <- maps::map("world", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

# Convert world to sp class
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(worldmap$names, ":"), "[", 1L)
world_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(worldmap, IDs = IDs, 
                                proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Convert world_sp to simple feature object
world_sf <- st_as_sf(world_sp)

# Add country ID
world_sf <- world_sf %>%
  mutate(region = map_chr(1:length(world_sp@polygons), function(i){
    world_sp@polygons[[i]]@ID
  }))

### Use st_within for the analysis

# Use st_within for all points
result_all <- st_within(point_sf, world_sf, sparse = FALSE)

# Filter the points by "Private" in the class column
point_private_sf <- point_sf %>% filter(class %in% "Private")

# Use st_within for private points
result_private <- st_within(point_private_sf, world_sf, sparse = FALSE)

### Calculate the total count of each polygon
# Store the result as ew columns "Count_all" and "Count_private" in world_sf
world_sf <- world_sf %>%
  mutate(Count_all = apply(result_all, 2, sum),
         Count_private = apply(result_private, 2, sum)) %>%
  # Calculate the percentage
  mutate(Percent = ifelse(Count_all == 0, Count_all, Count_private/Count_all * 100))

### Plot the data

# Convert world_sf to a data frame world_df 
world_df <- world_sf
st_geometry(world_df) <- NULL

# Get world data frame
world_data <- map_data("world")

# Merge world_data and world_df
world_data2 <- world_data %>%
  left_join(world_df, by = c("region"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = world_data2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Percent)) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
```